# Numbers is no longer shipped with OSX from Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, iwork, iwork-numbers

I heave heard that Mac OSX Snow Leopard shipped with Numbers, an app used to manipulate spreadsheets. But I can't find it inside my default Mac OSX Mountain Lion installation. Checking with App Store, I found that this app is now cost $20 ($19.95). So Apple remove Numbers from default shipment of OSX and make it paid product?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Numbers is only part of the [iWork](http://www.apple.com/iwork/) suite. OS X Snow Leopard only included iLife and iWork through the ["Mac Box Set"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003XKXN58). The regular Snow Leopard upgrade version for Leopard users didn't include this.

All subsequent versions of OS X never bundled full versions of iWork applications, only iLife. So, neither OS X Lion nor OS X Mountain Lion bundle full iWork installations.

iWork could be bought through regular Apple stores or their online shop. The regular distribution – beginning with the introduction of the Mac App Store – is a digital download though.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll stick with Google Spreadsheets.